# Angular are external lib import once?

Tags: angular, webpack

I've got the code below that using

in a lot of components (by import i).

Can I be sure that webpack import it

once and not all the time it's used?

```
import Big from 'big.js/big.mjs';
    type OgBig = typeof Big;

    export const BJ = {
      TO_FIXED: 2,
      toStr(value: number | string | OgBig): string {
        if (value instanceof Big) {
          return value.toFixed(this.TO_FIXED);
        }
        return Big(value).toFixed(this.TO_FIXED);
      },

      op(num: number | string): OgBig {
        return Big(num);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Your library is integrated with your application, every time you import the library into one of your components, you make it accessible from it.

Another thing, you said:

> I've got the code below that using in a lot of components.

Why not call your function directly into another component without going to copy your code into the components n times?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the really question is Can I be sure that webpack import it

once?

Comment: My answer implied that, of course, the import took place only once.